# Display users by role

Tags: user-roles

I am trying to display users by role, I am using the code below, but I am not sure if this code is correct.. but it works very well on the front page.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'role'    => 'Author',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           v
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args ); ?>

<ol>

<?php if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ); ?>

<li><?php echo $user->display_name ?></li>
<li><?php echo $user->user_email ?></li>
<li><?php echo $user->user_login ?></li>
<li><?php echo $user->ID ?></li>
<li><?php echo $user->user_url ?></li>
    
<?php } else { ?>
<li>No users found.</li>
<?php } ?>

</ol>
```

I really need advice on how to display it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your code: You want to list users with **author** role.

You're in the right direction, however, following are some tips to make your code better.

- Use **role id** in lowercase syntax. Change **Author** to `author` for `role` property.
- Get the results for once and avoid repeated calls. Save the results like `$authors = $user_query->get_the_results();` then, use `if (!empty($authors)) { ... }` to check and `foreach($authors as $author) {...}` to loop through.
- Wrap the actual results in `<ol>` or `<ul>` or other needed element, so, start the `<ol>` tag only if results are found and close the `</ol>` tag right after foreach loop. For the else content, use other HTML element such as `<p>` with a error code style class etc.
- Consider **pagination** for high number of users. Consider the case when the total matched users go up to 100+ to 1000s over the time.

After applying the given tips, the code is as follows: -

**Without pagination**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'role'    => 'author', // changed Author to author
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$authors_query = new WP_User_Query($args); // enhanced the variable name from $user_query to $authors_query 
$authors = $authors_query->get_results(); // saved the results for once to avoid repeated calls later on
?>

<?php if (!empty($authors)) { ?>
    <table> <!-- Replaced ol to table element -->
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>URL</th>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($authors as $user ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $user->display_name ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $user->ID ?> | <?php echo $user->user_login ?> | <?php echo $user->user_email ?> 
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $user->user_url ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } //endforeach ?>
        </table>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p class="no-results-notice">No authors found.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

**With pagination**

```
<?php

//Pagination
$page = isset($_GET['show_authors']) ? $_GET['show_authors'] : 1;
$authors_per_page = 20;  // you can change the number as needed
$total_pages = 1; // initial value; keep it one; we will update this after having actual number of users from query
$offset = $authors_per_page * ($page - 1);


$args = array(
    'role'    => 'author', // changed Author to author
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$authors_query = new WP_User_Query($args); // enhanced the variable name from $user_query to $authors_query 
$authors = $authors_query->get_results(); // saved the results for once to avoid repeated calls later on

// Updating variables for pagination.
$total_authors = $authors_query->get_total(); 
$total_pages = ceil($total_authors / $authors_per_page); 

?>

<?php if (!empty($authors)) { ?>
    <h2>We have <?php echo $total_authors; ?> authors in our website. </h2>
    <table> <!-- Replaced ol to table element -->
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>URL</th>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($authors as $user ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $user->display_name ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $user->ID ?> | <?php echo $user->user_login ?> | <?php echo $user->user_email ?> 
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $user->user_url ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } //endforeach ?>
        </table>

        <!-- Display Pagination Links -->
        <div class="authors-pagination">
            <?php                 
                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base'         => add_query_arg( 'show_authors', '%#%' ) ,
                    'total'        => $total_pages,
                    'current'      => $page,
                    'format'       => '',
                    'type'         => 'plain',
                    'end_size'     => 1,
                    'mid_size'     => 1,
                    'prev_next'    => true,
                    'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Previous', 'text-domain' ) ),
                    'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Next', 'text-domain' ) )
                ) );
            ?>
        </div>

<?php } else { ?>
    <p class="no-results-notice">No authors found.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Wow.. thank you for the complete explanation, really Appreciate It..., but i have one more question, is there any chance to display the role name of each user

Comment: i'm trying to achieve something like in this picture
[link](https://tinypic.host/i/9Kpm8)

Comment: Yes. In your case, if you're going to show only `authors` then, you can just write 'Author' in the <td> for that column. Let me know if you need to show ALL roles of the user.

Comment: i need to show all roles .. except the admin role, is it posible to do that, i have no idea..